# I cant get images from Node js nginx

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, vps

[There is my nginx configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDjTD.png)

I try to get images from server by using http://ip_adress/image_name.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Error log? you can check where its logging in terminal.

```
grep -r error_log <path/to/nginx.conf>
```

Also in the browser network tab (F12 Key) checking the server response could be useful.

Comment: In browser there is a message with status code 404 failed to load resourse, but on localhost it works